# Create 'Telegram' tag

Tags: support, tags

I was looking for some [Telegram related questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=telegram), and noted there's no tag for it, although there are quite a few questions about that topic.

Can someone with the [Create Tags privilege](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) can create that tag?

---

**Update to include more details regards the request:**

An excerpt example:

> Telegram is a cross-platform cloud-based messaging app. Use this tag for questions, issues and usage of Telegram apps running on iOS or macOS.

Example for questions that are entirely about Telegram (similar to questions about WhatsApp), and can fit the tag:

- [New user notifications on Telegram app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202725/new-user-notifications-on-telegram-app)
- [Run multiple instances of Telegram](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246940/run-multiple-instances-of-telegram)
- [where does it save downloaded mp3 file from telegram web service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244409/where-does-it-save-downloaded-mp3-file-from-telegram-web-service)

Questions that mention Telegram and so are shown in the [search results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=telegram), but shouldn't be tagged [telegram](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telegram) (or [telegram.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telegram.app)?):

- [How to type foreign currency symbols on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225707/how-to-type-foreign-currency-symbols-on-ios)
- [Some icons in random apps are misplaced and/or glitched](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314562/some-icons-in-random-apps-are-misplaced-and-or-glitched)
- [Terminal lagging macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259237/terminal-lagging-macos)

[About Telegram in general](https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-is-telegram-what-do-i-do-here):

> Telegram is a messaging app with a focus on speed and security, it’s super-fast, simple and free. You can use Telegram on all your devices at the same time — your messages sync seamlessly across any number of your phones, tablets or computers.

Comment: In case you don't feel voting on meta commonly - a -1 isn't that you should not have asked here (you should have and +1 to you / big thanks for asking) but that it's an indication that someone (me in one case) feels we shouldn't implement this now. You lose no reputation for - votes on meta and once it's worked out what the tag wiki scope would be - a second question with all that detail would likely get positive votes and be implemented (assuming it had consensus / significant net positive support and no big problems)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the meaning, good that now it's verified

Comment: Wow - this helps a lot - so telegram is a privacy forward / cross platform secure messaging app so that people that wanted different encryption than iMessage allows or different endpoints, they could use this app?

Comment: Pretty much, although I won't say most people switch because they want different encryption, it's usually because of the security focus, speed and tons of features.

Answer (score 3):

I'm disinclined to create a tag when the simple search function would find all telegram related posts. You've shown quite well that search works to find each and every telegram related post you cited.

Could you expand on your request a little by providing an answer here to your question that answers what the tag wiki for this tag will be? Keep one mind, a tag that is "posts tagged XYZ are about using product XYZ on Apple" generally never serve a function better than the search "criteria" I mentioned in the previous paragraph to "use search and not tags"

https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts

Here are the three questions I'd want to see answered before I would be the person to pull the trigger and make that tag taken from the link above:

1. *The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences* **What should the excerpt be for the telegram tag?**
2. **Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag** (this would be "telegram tag is about using telegram on Macs"
3. **Concentrate on what a tag means to the Ask Different community**

---

The good news is there are some volume of potential questions, so we should do the work to map out a wiki in case we do want to make this tag sooner rather than later.

Be sure to call out any questions with that search term where we would not want the tag to be applied and document it here in your answer / or a follow on post to create a tag with the wiki and use cases mapped out explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I updated the question with an example excerpt I think might be suitable and gave examples of questions that will fit the tag and some that won't

Comment: wow @arieljannai - that's a solid edit so I've immediately retracted my -1 on the question. I'll have a look later in the week (sports and family get my time now today) if we're set to make a tag or want to wait in specific.

Comment: Thanks! and enjoy :)